# Arduino 1.8.9 Won't Load

Tags: arduino-ide

I recently upgraded my windows10 from version 1803 to 1903. I had to do a clean install to accomplish it though, but my question is, I downloaded Adriano IDE 1.8.9 and installed it but it won't launch. It starts, then the window closes and that's it. Does anybody have any thoughts on what's going on? Or better yet what's not going on?

Thanks, Dennis

Comment: Where did you download the IDE from?

Comment: Does 1.8.10 work? https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software

Comment: Do you have a Java runtime installed? If so, what version?

Comment: I downloaded Arduino IDE 1.8.10 directly from Arduino.cc. I thought of the Java issue and downloaded the latest version for Windows10, 8.221(build 1.8.0_221-b11), and it's running. Oh, and I tried to load and run Arduino IDE version 1.8.9 that I'm running on my other machine, and it didn't run either. Seems like there is something in this new OS that Microsoft is not telling us about.